# Need Help Finding File for SSIS Tutorial

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to complete [the tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-1-creating-a-new-integration-services-project?view=sql-server-2017).

It lists a zip file called `SQL2012.Integration_Services.Create_Simple_ETL_Tutorial.Sample.zip` that at the very least has the flat file needed to complete the tutorial. All of the links either point to zip files that don't apply or lead to a page that tells you to click a "download tab" that isn't there. The "download archive" downloads a zip file but the required file isn't there either.

Has anyone managed to find the zip file?  If so, would you please post the link in your answer or tell me which MS tutorial I should run instead? I have SQL Server 2017 Express.

Comment: The odds that a reader has completed a specific tutorial that you have found is probably quite slim, but moreover, we seek self-contained questions here (i.e. everything that is needed to answer a question is in the question post itself). If this tutorial is not clear about where to obtain its files, then can you find another tutorial?

Comment: I thought that if a sql server guru were here that they might have knowledge about where Microsoft might have moved the files.  If this were some random tutorial on some random site, then I could see your point.

Comment: As for the question not being self contained, it would help me a great deal if you could tell me how.  I pointed to the tutorial that I was talking about by providing a link.  How could I have asked it better?

Comment: Well, I am giving my view that it is not on-topic; the self-contained rule protects questions against questions that will be no longer be understandable if the link breaks (and, see below, I think there's a lot of broken links here). You make a good point that it is a Microsoft site, and so therefore much more likely to be intended to be maintained. However, their material points to their CodePlex site, which was shutdown 18 months ago - MS is on GitHub now.

Comment: [This file](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/blob/61381ef939415fe019285def9450d7583df1fed0/docs/integration-services/ssis-how-to-create-an-etl-package.md) looks relevant, and it [points here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56827) - is that the file you are after, or close? If not, you could also try treating this as a customer service issue - MS should want to fix their materials, and hopefully send you a link/file in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual page with the download link is here - it's step 2, not the one you linked to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-2-adding-and-configuring-a-flat-file-connection-manager?view=sql-server-2017

It refers to this page

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=275027

Which has a button at the top right with this download link

https://codeplexarchive.blob.core.windows.net/archive/projects/MSFTISProdSamples/MSFTISProdSamples.zip

Which downloads a ZIP file called MSFTISProdSamples.zip

In that ZIP file is another ZIP file called sourceCode.zip

Inside this ZIP file in Kilimanjaro_RTM\Tutorial\Creating a Simple ETL Package\Sample Data, I'm guessing you will find your files.

Yes that page is incorrect, out of date and full of blind links.

It's also referring a lot to very old versions of SQL Sever

I managed to work this out though

**This is question is definitely not suitable for stack overflow but I want to illustrate that it's important to have strong problem solving skills. This is almost as important as just having the base technical skills for the product you are learning**

From the comments, @halfer also found this link which is a lot simpler to use

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56827

Comment: Thank you.  Not only were you immensely helpful by giving me the answer, you were even more helpful when you then explained why you believe it is not an appropriate question.

That being said, I did download that zip file.  And I did look through the folders.  I did not think a folder named Kilimanjaro_RTM had anything to do with the tutorial in question.  My mistake.  That doesn't mean I am a complete novice at solving problems.

Comment: Also.  A lesson I have learned is that you have to know when to quit beating your head against the wall and ask for help.

Comment: I also want you to know I upvoted this even though it doesn't count.  Sorry.

Comment: Last comment:

I have version 2017 and was looking for the tutorial for that version.  MS takes you to the 2012 one.

Comment: Yes it's a terrible and frustrating tutorial page and needs to be fixed or taken down. I can't believe it it's actually posted under SQL 2017. The flat files will probably work with SQL 2017 but the dtsx files most likely won't. There must be a better tutorial somewhere. I'm not sure if I explained that well but the reason the question is not suitable is it's basically html links and links rust over time (as evidenced by this terrible tutorial you are stuck with)

Comment: Actually the link in the comments looks way less complicated. I'll add it to my answer https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56827

Comment: I did get that, Nick.  My question depended on links that over time would likely break making the question unintelligible.  I can also see that thanks to how you explained it.